# How to decrypt JSON response using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, encryption, swift3, jsonresponse

I have Installed CryptoSwift framework by Pods. I am getting Encrypted data from server response. I am trying to do decrypt the data by using that below function:

```
func aesDecrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: self)!
    let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).decrypt([UInt8](data))
    let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
    return String(bytes: decryptedData.bytes, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Could not decrypt"
}
```

I have my model class in that I am getting response using Alamofire.

```
func getAllShops(data : [String : AnyObject]) {

    AFWrapper.requestPOSTURL(url, params: data, headers: nil, success: {(json) in
        print(json)
        let key = "My_Key"    // length == 32
        let iv = "My_iv"    // length == 16
        let encryptedData = json["encrypted"].string!  

        let enc = try! s.aesDecrypt(key: key, iv: iv)

    }, failure: {(Error) in
        print(Error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

How can I decrypt it and can get actual data? That function is not giving me the actual data. Is there any other way to decrypt the data?

Comment: What 's the error?

Comment: No error but in my print function it is giving ""Could not Decrypt".